# How to pass Ant property values set in one target to another which does not depend on the first

Tags: ant

Below is the example Ant task.

```
<target name="evalTask">
    <condition property="conditionValue" >
        <mycustomTask:evaluateCondition/>
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="checkAndUpdateFlag" unless="conditionValue">
    <property name="isEnabled" value="true"/>    
</target>

<target name="targetA" depends="checkAndUpdateFlag" unless="conditionValue">
    <echo message="Do something if the conditionValue is set" />
</target>

<target name="targetB">
    <echo message=" Value of isEnabled : ${isEnabled} />
</target>
```

In the above example target "evalTask" will set the property "conditionValue" is the my custom task "evalauateCondition returns true.

The target "targetA" will get executed only if the property "conditionValue" is set. Which I am working fine. But the property "isEnabled" in "checkAndUpdateFlag" is not getting set or it never gets inside "checkAndUpdateFlag" target and I still get the "isEnabled" property value inside "targetB" as ${isEnabled}. Basically the "isEnabled" is never set.

Below is the ant command I used to run this targets.

> ant targetA targetB

Any suggestion on why I am not getting the value of isEnabled in targetB ?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `evalTask` target never runs so the `conditionValue` property is never set.

Since the `conditionValue` property isn't set, the `checkAndUpdateFlag` target won't run:

```
<target name="checkAndUpdateFlag" unless="conditionValue">
```

The `unless="conditionValue"` tells Ant to skip the `<target name="checkAndUpdateFlag">` if the `conditionValue` property isn't set.

### Possible solution #1:

Add a `depends` to `checkAndUpdateFlag`:

```
<target name="checkAndUpdateFlag" unless="conditionValue" depends="evalTask">
    <!-- ... -->
```

### Possible solution #2:

Call the `evalTask` target first on the command line:

> ant evalTask targetA targetB